# Is there a way of adding a button or a pop up message against a dynamic day

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that adds a number of tables depending on number of days worked and at the end of the week I want it to add a link to another tab for a weekly review. For instance if they work monday, tuesday, thursday and friday, then when they are completing the last day (friday in this instance), for it to have a button that hyperlinks or at least reminds them to now complete the weekly review

I've tried searching for code, I've tried adding a button, but it only adds a button if you do it yourself, I can't see how to add it as a piece of code, because the number of rows in the spreadsheet is dependent on the number of days worked, so I can't just add it as something already there

Whatever day is the last working day (could be any day of the week), then a reminder comes up to go to the weekly review tab (or take them to it)

Comment: You can add a button in a dialog or a sidebar with html.

Comment: Welcome. Take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve]. Titles should be descriptive of the problem. Your question should include a statement of a single problem. And in most cases you should include the code you have written to try to solve the problem. And that code should be the smallest it needs to be to represent the problem.